# AppSync List Query Returns Empty Array from JS Client App, but Populated Array from AppSync Console

Tags: reactjs, graphql, clojurescript, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

When running a list query from the AppSync console, I get back an array with 3 items (this is expected, as I have three corresponding items in my DynamoDB table).

When I run the exact same query from my React client application, I get an empty array. I've tried messing around with the @auth decorator in my schema.graphql file, but so far to no avail. I also experience the same behavior when running the query from Postman - I get an empty items array.

Type definition in schema.graphql:

```
type Item @model @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner },
    { allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read] }]) {
    id: ID!
    itemName: String!
    anotherProperty: String!
    anotherProperty: String!
    anotherProperty: String!
    anotherProperty: String
    anotherProperty: AnotherType @connection
    anotherProperty: String
    anotherProperty: String
    anotherProperty: String
    anotherProperty: String
    anotherProperty: String
    anotherProperty: SomeType @connection
    anotherProperty: [SomeOtherType] @connection(keyName: "byItemID", fields: ["id"])
    anotherProperty: String
    anotherProperty: [YetAnotherType] @connection(keyName: "byItemID", fields: ["id"])
}
```

Client code where I call the API (ClojureScript):

```
(re-frame/reg-event-fx
              ::list-items
              (fn list-items-handler []
                (-> (.graphql API (graphqlOperation "query { listItems { items { itemName } } }"))
                                 (.then (fn list-items-res [url]
                                          (js/console.log url))))))
```

Response to call from client application:

```
{"data":{"listItems":{"items":[]}}}
```

Same query from the AppSync Console:

```
query ListItems {
  listItems {
    items {
      itemName
    }
  }
}
```

Response to call from AppSync Console:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listItems": {
      "items": [
        {
          "itemName": "Thingy"
        },
        {
          "itemName": "Contraption"
        },
        {
          "itemName": "Apparatus"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I suspect it has something to do with the permissions set with @auth, but I can't figure out what that might be. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: something with auth permissions. the provider is iam. Why dont you set the api auth in the settings to api key and then try with postman if it gives data. That way you will know it is the permissions issue